# Fatal error Class 'tidy' not found com Wamp + PHP 5.5.12

Tags: php, wamp, php-document

Em um projeto que estou trabalhando no meu trabalho atual, deparei com alguns problemas que realmente estão dando dor de cabeça:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue linha de código do arquivo `TransformDoc.inc.php`

```
public function validatorXHTML()
{

    ob_start();
    ?>
    <html>a html document</html>
    <?php
    $html = ob_get_clean();

    // Specify configuration
    $config = array(
               'indent'         => true,
               'output-xhtml'   => true,
               'wrap'           => 200);

    // Tidy
    $tidy = new tidy; //Linha 315(ERRO)  
    $tidy->parseString($html, $config, 'utf8');
    $tidy->cleanRepair();

    // Output
    echo $tidy;

}
```

Linha 315:

> $tidy = new tidy;

Answer (score 0):

Vamos supor que você esteja utilizando Wampserver 2.0. Com ele já aberto (em execução) você só precisa seguir esse caminho e clicar no ícone Wamp Server com o botão direito do mouse na sua **bandeja do sistema>PHP>PHP extensions>php_tidy**, como é mostrado na figura:

[image: em seguida, ir PHP> extensões PHP e clique em php_tidy]

Feito isso, a classe estará ativada no PHP.ini

Se restar dúvidas, por favor, não deixe de questionar.

abs